# Ajax upatepanel on user control, parent's inline style not rendered by IE

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, internet-explorer, user-controls

I have a asp.net page, the main content section displays the custom html content from the database.  To the right of it, it has a few user control that lets the user make drop down selections and go to its perspective links.

So it's something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
 <atlas:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <%=Session["xyz"].ToString()%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="rightContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-left: 4px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 239px;">
            <uc18:x ID="x1" runat="server" referer="Home" />
            <uc17:y ID="y1" runat="server" />
            <uc4:z ID="z1" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

The user contorls are pretty straight forward.  Each one of them has drop downs.  If one selects, it populates the next one..etc, and they are wrapped around a update panel so the page won't referesh itself on selection.

The issue i have is when the page first loaded, the content in <%=Session["xyz"].ToString()%>, which sometimes have css inline style, loads fine.  However as soon as the user clicks on the first drop down of any user control, the css inline style disappears.

My question is why is the inline style not being rendered by the browser again on ajax postback (only happening in IE, firefox is ok)?  What should i do about this?
Thanks in advance.

Angela.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's bug with Atlas.  If i use the asp.net ajax, it works fine.  Unfortunately i cannot change Atals ajas to asp.net for the time being.  My easiest solution was to let the full post back happen.